# Grouping locations of people

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, localization

I have a pandas dataframe containing information about a person's location, including their `latitude`, `longitude`, and `story`. To break down this dataframe into smaller chunks, each containing 9 rows, I need to consider the following requirements:

Each chunk of the dataframe should not contain rows where both the "latitude" and "longitude" values are identical, as this indicates that both individuals live in the same building. However, within each chunk, the `latitude` and `longitude` values should be similar, implying that the people in that chunk live in close proximity to each other, but not at the exact same location.

Perhaps defining the term "close proximity" could prove beneficial. The simplest approach is to determine the closest neighbor. For instance, if individual `a` is nearby `b`, and `b` is the closest to `c`, and `c` is the next nearest to `d` (and so on), this ensures that the cluster (chunk) is composed of people from the same neighborhood.

In essence, we seek an algorithm that groups individuals into chunks based on these criteria, resulting in clusters of people who live in close proximity to each other but not too close.
In the very last step I will append each chunk to create one big dataframe.

```
df = {
"latitude": [49.5619579, 49.5619579, 49.5628938, 49.5628938, 49.5630028, 49.5633175, 49.56397639999999, 49.5659508, 49.566359, 49.56643220000001, 49.56643220000001, 49.5672061, 49.567729, 49.5677449, 49.5679685, 49.5679685, 49.568089, 49.5686342, 49.5687609, 49.5688543, 49.5690616, 49.5695834, 49.5706579, 49.5711228, 49.5713705, 49.5716422, 49.5717749]
"longitude": [10.9995758, 10.9995758, 11.000319, 11.000319, 10.9990996, 10.9993819, 11.004145, 10.9873409, 11.0003023, 10.9999593, 10.9999593, 10.9935709, 11.0011213, 10.9954016, 10.9982288, 10.9982288, 10.9894035, 10.9896749, 10.9887881, 10.9975928, 10.9931367, 10.9851579, 10.9853273, 10.9912959, 10.9939141, 10.9910182, 10.9867083]
}
"story": [2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 5.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0]
```

The actual dataframe is much larger. Here are the first 9 rows:

```
MasterKitchen_Latitude  MasterKitchen_Longitude MasterKitchen_Story
0   49.561958               10.999576                 2.0
1   49.561958               10.999576                 4.0
2   49.562894               11.000319                 3.0
3   49.562894               11.000319                 4.0
4   49.563003               10.999100                 1.0
5   49.563317               10.999382                 2.0
6   49.563976               11.004145                 3.0
7   49.565951               10.987341                 1.0
8   49.566359               11.000302                 3.0
```

## Code from ongoing discussion

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a new column "lat_long" by combining latitude and longitude as strings
df["lat_long"] = df["latitude"].astype(str) + "_" + df["longitude"].astype(str)

# Now, you can use groupby on the "lat_long" column
grouped_df = df.groupby("lat_long")

print(grouped_df.mean())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use kmeans cluster to get k locations then every row can be split into a location.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

I think this may useful

```
def get_letter_type(letter):
    if letter.lower() in 'aeiou':
        return 'vowel'
    else:
        return 'consonant'


grouped = df.groupby(get_letter_type, axis=1)
```

but in your case, you need to know some cluster center to define the groupby function like get_letter_type

```
    df = {
        "latitude": [49.5619579, 49.5619579, 49.5628938, 49.5628938, 49.5630028, 49.5633175, 49.56397639999999,
                     49.5659508, 49.566359, 49.56643220000001, 49.56643220000001, 49.5672061, 49.567729, 49.5677449,
                     49.5679685, 49.5679685, 49.568089, 49.5686342, 49.5687609, 49.5688543, 49.5690616, 49.5695834,
                     49.5706579, 49.5711228, 49.5713705, 49.5716422, 49.5717749],
        "longitude": [10.9995758, 10.9995758, 11.000319, 11.000319, 10.9990996, 10.9993819, 11.004145, 10.9873409,
                      11.0003023, 10.9999593, 10.9999593, 10.9935709, 11.0011213, 10.9954016, 10.9982288, 10.9982288,
                      10.9894035, 10.9896749, 10.9887881, 10.9975928, 10.9931367, 10.9851579, 10.9853273, 10.9912959,
                      10.9939141, 10.9910182, 10.9867083],
        "story": [2.0, 4.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 5.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0,
                  3.0,
                  2.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0]
    }
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    print(df.head(3))


    def get_nearby(row):
        return f"{row['latitude']:.3f}_{row['longitude']:.3f}"


    df["new"] = df.apply(get_nearby, axis=1)

    grouped_df = df.groupby("new")

    print(grouped_df.mean())
```

Comment: But k-means will cluster people who have same values for both ``latitude`` and ``longitude`` values. I need a way to prevent this. I was hoping to just use pandas.

Comment: new a column name lat_long which link latitude and longitude to a str like  49.562894_ 49.562894 then you can use gourp on this column.

Comment: You mean ``groupby``? I don't see how this helps. Creating such a new column though is not the problem though.

Comment: @PParker yes, create a new column and groupby on it

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestions (see code above). But I don't see, how this helps me to sort people according to my requirements

Comment: @PParker I think you should define similarity clearly fisrt. if a nearby b, and b nearby c, a and c should be in same category?

Comment: Good point. I have changed my questions to make this point clear! Please have a look above!

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand. Maybe you can show me a complete example based on my dataframe? I do not understand the purpose of your custom function and how to apply it to the problem. If I understand you correctly, you want to use both kmeans and groupby?

Comment: @PParker,  If you do not want cluster, can grid will be satisfy your situation. I mean the latitude and longitude construct a grad system,  put peoples in a same small grid into a cluster.

Comment: Well, if this sound like a reasonable approach to you...I am open for this, but I do not know how to apply this to my problem

Comment: I modify the answer